# Copy generated char from array to a new array

Tags: c, arrays

I've been trying to work this out for the last 2 hours, yet still no success. Basically, I have a generated list of characters that I need to process. Right now I've 2 files, one handles the generation and writes it to a file, the other reads from it and works on it. I want to change that. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char re1[2] = { '1','2' };
    char re2[2] = { '3','4' };
    char re3[2] = { '5','6' };
    char re4[2] = { '7','8' };
    char re5[2] = { '9' };
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    char nil[100];

    for (a = 0; a<2; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b<2; b++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c<2; c++)
            {
                for (d = 0; d<2; d++)
                {
                    for (e = 0; e<1; e++)
                    {
                        nil[0] = (re1[a], re2[b], re3[c], re4[d], re5[e]);
                        printf("%c\n", nil[0]);

                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I just do this: `printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n"re1[a],re2[b],re3[c],re4[d],re5[e]);` Then I get what I need, but I want to write that combination, let's say 13589 into `nil` so that I can later call, let's say `printf("%c%c",nil[0],nil[3])` and get 18 out. I'm probably doing something stupid or missing something obvious, but that's what I have so far. In the original files I have this:

```
FILE *myfile;
myfile = fopen("out.txt","r");
```

and

```
fscanf(myfile,"%s",&nil[0]);
```

after that, I can use `nil[0]` and such to check the characters.

EDIT: changed the character in the arrays

Comment: Time to learn about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: BTW, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: Change `'W'` to a different value on each line, I cannot understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Ôrel changed it, I think it should be more clear now.

Comment: OK, I'm dumb. Just had to write `nil[0]=re1[a]` , `nil[1]=re2[b]` and so forth, then it works. Damn it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm dumb. Just had to write `nil[0]=re1[a]` , `nil[1]=re2[b]` and so forth, then it works. Damn it.

Comment: Or use `memcpy`

Comment: Or stick the array in a struct.